# How to assign SQL query results to a variable(Robot Framework) to input in application edit text?

Tags: python, database, robotframework

Using MySQL and Robot Framework combination along with robot database library and pymysql library.

```
Connecting Database
Connect to database                         pymysql  ${DB_NAME}  ${DB_USER_NAME}  ${DB_USER_PASSWORD}  ${DB_HOST}  ${DB_PORT}
Sleep                                       ${wait_time}
Log to console                              Database Connection is established successfully!
```

And able to fetch the DB table data and printed on IDE console. Problem is that not able to assign query results to a robot variable to input for an edit-text inside the application.

```
${queryResult1}                             QUERY  SELECT COLUMN1 FROM  ${TABLE_NAME};
${query_results}                            Selenium2Library.Get Text  ${queryResult1}
Log to Console                              ${query_results}
```

Application Script

```
Sleep                               5s
Selenium2Library.Input Text                          ${username}     ${query_results}}
Sleep                               5s
Selenium2Library.Input Text                          ${password}     ${query_results}}
Sleep                               5s
Selenium2Library.Click element                       ${login_button}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return value of a query in the database library is a list of tuples - each list member is a response row, and the tuple is the column values in it.
When you used `queryResult1` in the keywords you were actually using this two-dimensional object - not the text in the database, as you might have expected.

To get the value you're after you have to "unpack" the object; presuming you want to get the first column from the first row, that is the simplest approach:

```
${DB value}=    Set Variable    ${queryResult1[0][0]}
```

The first index is the row number, the second - the column; the indices are zero-based.

Then you can use `${DB value}` in the follow-up keywords.

Comment: @Tandor , Thanks for answer. Could you pls share that how did you have stored value to ${queryResult1[0][0]} variable? Sample could be very much useful.

Comment: The moment you executed this keyword - `${queryResult1} QUERY  SELECT COLUMN1 FROM  ${TABLE_NAME};`, the query was ran on the sql server, and some result was returned. The result is stored for you in the shape I've described - a list of tuples, e.g. in python speak, `[(row0_COLUMN1,), (row1_COLUMN1,), (row2_COLUMN1,)]` - a 2 dimensional object (a matrix, in math speak). Imagine it as a table; so to get a cell's value (a member of the matrix), you specify its position - the row (the count starts from 0), and the column -  `${queryResult1[0][0]}`.

Comment: That was an handful answer. Thanks